# avarage result always 0.0 what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    int n,i;
    float num[100],sum=0.0,avg;
    
    printf("please enter a number between 1-100: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    while(n<1||n>100){
        printf("wrong number, enter again: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d. number: ",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&num[i]);
        sum+=num[i];
        }
        
    
    avg=sum/n;
    printf("avarage %.2f",&avg);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("avarage %.2f",&avg)` is incorrect. Try using `printf("avarage %.2f", avg)` instead. (you use `&` with scanf because you have to pass a pointer to an object, but you don't need to do that to print its value)

Comment: A modern compiler would have warned you about this problem.  Mine says: `warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'float *'`.  You'll find C *much* easier to learn using a compiler that helps you by finding easy mistakes like this!

Answer (score 1):

In last `printf("...", <float>)` you shold not send an adress of sum. Remove &.